# post json body in java

Tags: java, json, http-post, minecraft

I'm trying to whip together a fast'n'dirty Java program using HTTP-POST to launch Minecraft via a .jar or .bat file (haven't gotten that far). In the POST, I am sending the following:

```
{
"agent":{
    "name": "Minecraft",
    "version": "1"
},
"username": "user",
"password": "pass",
"clientToken": "token"
}
```

but have no idea how to do this.

I have set up this List

```
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("agent", ""));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Minecraft"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", "1"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "user"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clientToken", "token"));
```

but don't believe it to be formatted correctly to match the above JSON. How should it look?

(I am a newbie at Java (or have very little knowledge of everything; my current code contains snippets from various websites), so please be as detailed as possible)

Comment: You better create a json string an post it to request body.

Comment: How would I do that, Juned?

Comment: Either just use that JSON String directly, or use the built-in Java JSON classes (i.e. JSONObject, JSONArray, etc). Check on Google.

Comment: How would I use the JSON string directly? If you wouldn't mind, could you whip up a quick example?

Comment: Are you saying you want to create that JSON string or parse it?